# Attempting to write python files to a directory results in Permission Error 13

Tags: python

I'm trying to write python files to a directory but whenever I run the code I get errno 13. I've looked at a lot of solutions but none of them are working for me. My code is as follows:

```
import os
dirget = (os.getcwd())
findir = (dirget + "\\files")
if not os.path.exists(dirget + "\\files"):
    os.makedirs(dirget + "\\files")
with open(findir, 'w+') as file:
        file.write("hello")
```

The error I recieve is:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 
'C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop\\files'
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That means you don't have sufficient permission to write to the file, like the error message says. Check the permission of the file.

Comment: I checked the file permissions and it says I have all permissions but it's still not working.

Comment: You're trying to open the dir as a file. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Perhaps. In that case how do I write the file in the dir without opening the dir as a file?

Comment: so what you do is trying to open the directory "files" (which you create). Instead you should open a file.  like: `with open('findir' + '\\yourfilename.txt', 'w+') as file:`

Comment: Thank you so much! This solved the issue for me.